# StarterAssetsInputs OnLook is not triggering in Unity New Input System

Tags: unity, c#

I have StarterAssetsInputs script which based in new input system but it's onLook event is not triggering at all. Reamining functions like onSprint, onJump are working fine. But unable to find why onlook is not trigger. Here is the screenshot of the settings:
[image]

Here is the part of script:

```
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM && STARTER_ASSETS_PACKAGES_CHECKED
        public void OnMove(InputValue value)
        {
            MoveInput(value.Get<Vector2>());
        }

        public void OnLook(InputValue value)
        {
            if (cursorInputForLook)
            {
                LookInput(value.Get<Vector2>());
            }
        }

        public void OnJump(InputValue value)
        {

            JumpInput(value.isPressed);
        }

        public void OnSprint(InputValue value)
        {
            SprintInput(value.isPressed);
        }
#endif
```

Comment: Blind guessing, but since the script somehow needs to know what are you looking at and you didn't assign a camera in the same script, can that be your error?

Comment: I think "OnLook" here refers to "When the `Look` input vector (gamepad right stick or mouse delta) takes a non-zero value" rather than "When a thing is looked-at". Can you show us the code you're using to react to the `OnLook` and `OnSprint`/`OnJump` messages so we can reproduce this test case?

Comment: I have updated the code, but unable to understand that its working again,